# What does the error "Segmentation fault(core dumped)" mean?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

i am trying to implement a for-loop using assembler coding and in each iteration the value of the register edi should be printed. When I try to execute my code, I get an Error "Segmentation fault(core dumped)". Can somebody please tell me what does this error mean and are there any mistakes in my code?

```
section .text
         global _start

_start:
        xor edi,edi

loop:    
        add edi,'0'
        
        ;print i
        mov edi,1
        mov esi,1
        mov ecx,[edi]
        mov edx,1
        syscall
        
        sub edi,'0'
        
        inc edi   
        cmp edi,5
        jl loop
```

Comment: `mov edi,1` overwrites the `'0'` value you had before, but neither of those are valid addresses so it makes no sense to try to use an `[edi]` memory source operand.  Also, Linux's write `syscall` takes a pointer in RSI, and ignores RCX (in fact the syscall instruction itself writes RCX before the kernel even gets control.)  I wonder if you copied  the ECX part from 32-bit code that used `int 0x80`.  (Where it would still be wrong...)

Answer (score 2):

It means that you attempted to access address space in a way that's not permitted. For example:

- you might have tried to write to a read only location
- you might have tried to read from a write only location
- you might have tried to execute code from a location without execute permissions set
- you might have tried to read or write from an address either not mapped at all, or mapped with all kinds of access disallowed

And there are a few more conditions that cause this signal to trip. Have a look at the man pages of `mmap` and `mprotect` to get an idea of what's possible.

Comment: Note that Linux also delivers a SIGSEGV for x86 `#GP` exceptions, not just invalid page faults (`#PF`).  So for example, you can SIGSEGV by trying to run a privileged instruction like `mov cr3, rax` or `in al, 0x80` in user-space, or an invalid interrupt like `int 0x44`.  But yes in this case clearly accessing absolute address `1` is the problem; Linux will refuse to map that page even if you try with mmap, unless you change a sysctl setting: https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr

Comment: Strictly speaking Linux will disallow mapping the first page. That is good for several reasons: The NUL pointer lives there (on Linux) as well as several in-band signalled through "pointers" error codes. Same also applies for the first "negative" page. Essentially on Linux any address inside the range -4096…4095 can safely be assumed to be invalid. And in case you're wondering about negative addresses: The kernel lives there (if you case negative pointers to their uintptr_t counterparts, they are in the top half).

Comment: Are you *sure* about the `0..4095` part of that range?  https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr says some user-space things like WINE for 16-bit user-space, and dosemu, need `mmap_min_addr = 0`.  You're right about the top page being used for error codes and reserved against being mmaped ([Why can't I mmap(MAP\_FIXED) the highest virtual page in a 32-bit Linux process on a 64-bit kernel?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47712502)), but with 4096 possible codes it doesn't really need more. If you want to give up the safety of NULL-deref actually faulting in user-space, I thought the kernel allowed it.

Comment: In fact, according to my linked question, I did actually try it back then and find I could mmap the zero page, with that test code.

Comment: @PeterCordes it depends on how your system is configured. It would be nice if we could set this on a per-executable base in some ELF header field. The core of the problem is, that memory protections happen on the page level, as far as the MMPU is concerned.

Comment: Not sure what your point is about memory protection having page granularity.  You *want* to disallow deref of tiny addresses like `[1]` as well; that can happen in compiled code with `p->member` with `p=NULL`, not just buggy hand-written asm that mixes up pointers and integers.  That's why `mmap_min_addr` defaults to 64k, not 4096.  As for it being a system-wide setting, mmap doesn't usually (or ever?) actually pick 0 randomly even when allowed, so it doesn't tend to cause problems (except needing to change config for WINE).  Probably not worth extra space in a task_struct vs. 1 global!